# openLDAP N Way Multimaster

Tags: openldap

Does anyone know what the maximum number of nodes can be configured in a OpenLDAP N Way Multimaster configuration?

I have been looking through the internet and all I see in the number of database transactions replicated and not the actual number of nodes that can be used to communicate with each other.

Answer (score 1):

I have confirmed, there is no limitation in nodes with N way mirror mode configuration in OpenLDAP.

Just some information related to mirror-mode, Mirror mode is not Multiple master replication as some people thinks. This is because writes have to go to just one of the mirror nodes at a time.

Refer arguments against mirror-mode in http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/guide.html#MirrorMode%20replication